# iOS crashing on launch - Can't recreate on any device

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've been having issues getting my app to be approved by Apple and I've tried multiple devices with no luck in recreating this. Does the below log file help identify what the issue is specifically?

```
{"app_name":"Instant Delay Repay","timestamp":"2018-08-24 10:14:55.60 -0700","app_version":"1.3","slice_uuid":"e3f8474c-ce25-399c-bde2-39826ea9a0ed","adam_id":1422836598,"build_version":"0","bundleID":"com.traintimes.instantdelayrepay","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)","incident_id":"16CC621D-2141-44BE-BDA0-7333AAC1CCA4","name":"Instant Delay Repay"}
Incident Identifier: 16CC621D-2141-44BE-BDA0-7333AAC1CCA4
CrashReporter Key:   316df79fad95f032c78236a07518a02ba5969f46
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Instant Delay Repay [3647]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E37F2584-2B61-4B4B-80BC-66E3599464BA/Instant Delay Repay.app/Instant Delay Repay
Identifier:          com.traintimes.instantdelayrepay
Version:             0 (1.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.traintimes.instantdelayrepay [1797]


Date/Time:           2018-08-24 10:14:55.0774 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-08-24 10:14:34.9410 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    6.80.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.traintimes.instantdelayrepay exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 18.77 seconds |  | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 40.880 (user 40.880, system 0.000), 68% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 4.870, 8% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

Comment: Actually your application is crashing because of the watch dog. watch dog will automatically kill the application if any method or service takes indefinite time to respond back. do you have any setup service at start that might take indefinite time?